# Having issues to access props when calling a component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components, material-ui

I have an `FilterSliders` component built with Material UI. I have passed a prop called `{classes.title}` using destructuring `const { classes }: any = this.props;`. I am trying access the prop when calling the component, but I don't access to it & my code throws an error.

**My `FilterSliders` component:**

```
import './FilterSliders.scss';

import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import Slider from '@material-ui/lab/Slider';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import React from 'react';

const styles = {
  root: {
    width: '100%',
  },
  slider: {
    padding: '22px 0px',
  },
};

class FilterSliders extends React.Component {
  public static propTypes: { classes: PropTypes.Validator<object>; };
  public state = {
    value: 50,
  };

  public handleChange = (event: any, value: any): any => {
    this.setState({ value });
  };

  public render() {
    const { classes }: any = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={`filter__sliders ${classes.root}`}>
        <Typography>{classes.title}</Typography>
        <Slider
          classes={{ container: classes.slider }}
          value={value}
          aria-labelledby='label'
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
}

FilterSliders.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};

export default withStyles(styles)(FilterSliders);
```

Trying to access the `title` prop when calling the component:

```
<FilterSliders title='Submitted' />
```

It doesn't work & throws an error:

```
Type '{ title: string; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<InferProps<{ classes: Validator<object>; }>, "classes">, never> & StyledComponentProps<"root" | "slider"> & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Property 'title' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & Pick<Pick<InferProps<{ classes: Validator<object>; }>, "classes">, never> & StyledComponentProps<"root" |
```

### Update

@Richard suggested me to declare a PropType for `title` prop...I tried like so:

```
FilterSliders.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
};
```

& like so:

```
FilterSliders.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
};
```

I got just errors..

Comment: `title` is a property of `this.props` not `this.props.classes`, try to use `{this.props.title}`

Comment: Can you post the error stacktrace please ?

Comment: @RichardHaddad I have updated my post now with the error that I get when calling the component.

Comment: You should define `title` in your `propTypes`.

Comment: Can you provide me the right way of doing so & explanation? Don't assume anything I'm still quite new to React, TypeScript & Material UI.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've misunderstood how properties work in React, when you set a property to a component (eg: `<FilterSliders title='Submitted' />`) that property will be added to the component's `this.props` object.

In this case, because you're using material-ui, `withStyles(styles)` will add a `classes` property to the component that has the same properties as `styles` (classes names).

So, to access the classes you can use `this.props.classes` or `const { classes }: any = this.props` and to access the other properties that the parent component sets you use just `this.props.propertyName` (eg: `this.props.title` or `const { title }: string = this.props`).

Which means that you should be using something like this:

```
public render() {
    const { classes }: any = this.props;
    const { title }: string = this.props;
    const { value } = this.state;

    return (
      <div className={`filter__sliders ${classes.root}`}>
        <Typography>{title}</Typography>
        <Slider
          classes={{ container: classes.slider }}
          value={value}
          aria-labelledby='label'
          onChange={this.handleChange}
        />

      </div>
    );
  }
```

And you should also change the component's `propType`

```
FilterSliders.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  title: PropTypes.string.isRequired
};
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer & the amazing explanation!